# jQuery Validate plugin that also applies to future forms

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate, jquery-on

I have this html

```
<form class="validate"><!-- various inputs here --></form>
```

and this js

```
$("form.validate").validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo(element.closest("div.error_box"));
  },
  errorElement: "div",
  errorClass: "form_error"
});
```

Then suppose that, after a certain event (i.e. click on a button) i load a new form (via ajax) like that above. Or, i refresh completely that part of code, so my form is brand new and my validation is lost.

I'm trying to attach/re-attach validation to it, without re-calling validate() on ajax call's success callback.

A bit like the "old" jquery live method;

Can i use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in some way? If the method "on" can bind an "event" to new elements, why we can't apply the whole validation?

Comment: Why?  Are you trying to save code?  No matter where you put `.validate(options)`, the amount of code will be the same.

Comment: it's not the same amount of code, assume that i have 10 ajax callbacks.. i have to put `.validate(options)` ten times.. i don't want to care about that.

Comment: Since you have to call `.validate()` on every single `form` no matter what you do, then it's ten calls... same amount of code.  I gave you a practical suggestion where you can at least move options out and call `validator.setDefaults(options)` once.

Comment: that's not really true. i can call .validate once for multiple forms, why not? if i call $("form.validate").validate, every form with class validate will acquire validation

Comment: That still will **not** work if the `form` does not exist yet... and I really wanted that to work:  http://jsfiddle.net/C7jmt/

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT as per Comments and edited OP**:

> "What is the smartest way to attach jquery validate on elements (i.e.
>   **new forms**) that will appear later"

If you're talking about creating/loading a whole new form, then AFAIK, this is the only way... call `.validate()` immediately after you load/create the new form...

```
$('#my_NEW_form').validate({
    // your options
});
```

If all of your forms share the same options, you can also use the `setDefaults` method once to avoid declaring them over and over...

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
    // your repeated options
});
```

See:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/setDefaults#defaults

---

**EDIT 2:**

> "Can I use `.on` in some way? If the method "on" can bind an "event" to
>   new elements, why we can't apply the whole validation?"

Because it's used for binding `events`, not plugins, and...  `.validate()` is not an event.  [jQuery `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is used to automatically bind a `function` to an `event` as new `element`'s are dynamically created.

Again, you never explained the purpose of your question... WHY do you want to do this?  To save code?

Back to where we started... simply calling `$('#newform').validate({/*options*/})` within your `ajax` `success` callback function is the exact same amount of code as what'd you have to put anywhere else.

---

Original answer follows.  I'm leaving it in place because some of the general information about `.validate()` initialization still applies.

---

I assume that your question is basically, *"how can I apply rules to field inputs that are added dynamically?"*

> "What is the smartest way to attach jquery validate on elements that
>   will appear later"

By using the plugin's built-in `rules('add')` method for applying rules dynamically.

> "There's a way better than call jquery validate again in each AJAX
>   call's .success() handler?"

You actually should not call `.validate()` again.  Once `.validate()` is called once to initialize the plugin on the form, calling it again, will **not** change the rules.  There's a method for that.

Inside whatever `ajax` `success` callback function that adds your new field elements, use [the built-in `rules('add')` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules).

```
$('#yourfield').rules('add', {
    required: true,
    // other rules,
    messages: { // optional
        required:  "your optional custom message"
    }
});
```

Use a jQuery `.each()` if you need to apply the rules to several fields at once....

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/ucYkY/**

Comment: no, i don't mean that. i know that, and is not a problem.

i mean future "forms" that come from ajax reponse (overlay, refresh of page parts.. etc)

i've added a clarification to the question about that now

Comment: thanks, but there must be a way to call the validate only once per "selector". i've seen that jquery forms have this option (called delegation) https://github.com/malsup/form/ and i've used it, but i can't grok the source code and reapply it to jquery-validate

Comment: @avastreg, what do you mean "once per selector"?... your new form should have a new selector, or even calling `.validate()` again won't work.  At this point, I think you need to show more code in your OP because what you're trying to achieve is very unclear.

Comment: @avastreg, [initializing the plugin before the target exists is not an option with the jQuery Validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). When you call `.validate()`, the target form **must** _already_ exist. That's just the way this plugin is designed.

Comment: i know that's not an option, otherwise i won't be here to ask :)
i was asking if there's some other way to achieve that behaviour (i've updated the question)

Comment: @avastreg, Yes, I've already fully answered your question. IMO, what you ask is not achievable. See my Edit #2 above.

Comment: ok i'll leave this open for a while, then, if nobody else answers, i'll definitely close the question as "not achievable"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/) which uses html5 data attributes and everything is handled by the plugin.

All you do is write your html and add data attributes as needed. Very declarative and no Javascript involved, unless you need a custom validation function

As long as your dynamic input fields have the correct data attributes, parsley will find them

Comment: i've used it then i've returned to jquery-validate. parsley is very good with simple validation, but when things gets complicated, then problems come. i need various custom validations

Comment: Could you please explain what's preventing you using Parsley instead of jquery-validate in your case? Parsley should be cool only with data- attribues for a wide majority but powerfull to handle any complex validation. I'm interested by your case / bugs / feedbacks. Thanks! guillaume [at] wisembly [dot] com